# How to compare that all rows match between two dataframes on a subset of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two datasets, `input` and `output`, with some data transformations happening on input to get the resultant output where no. of rows and columns with column headers, remain same.

The datasets has around 5000 rows and 60 columns. The transformations are only on two columns, which got converted from one string value to another string value.

I need to compare and see that all row and columns data matches between input and output for all the non-transformed (58) columns (ignoring two transformed columns)

what I have done so far (using Pandas, Python and Pytest):

1. Converted both the input and output files as data frames

> (input_df and output_df)

.

2. Wrote below code, to match and compare each of the columns by getting a boolean as below.

> ```
> def test_matching_data():
>     assert (input_df['col1'].isin(output_df['col1']).any())
>     assert (input_df['col2'].isin(output_df['col2']).any())
>     assert (input_df['col3'].isin(output_df['col3']).any())
> ```

Not sure if this is correct approach, as this does not look elegant and certainly not scalable, as I need to add 60 lines this way. And make changes, if there are more columns added or deleted in data sets for future transformations.

How can I do this comparison of two dataframes, either in Pandas or Pyspark, and compare if each 'cell' data is matching between input and output dataframes, for all the respective non transformed columns ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll).

If `col1` and `col2` are the 2 columns you modified you can do this :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

other_cols = [F.col(c) for c in input_df.columns if c not in ["col1", "col2"]]

diff_df = input_df.select(*other_cols).exceptAll(output_df.select(*other_cols))

assert (diff_df.count() == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me here. Tried it and for me ```diff_df.count()``` is not giving me '0'. It seems is giving me the number of column values which have been transformed. But my test is to check if each of the non-transformed column data (ie., each cell value) is matching in both input and output data sets.   I have tried ```input_df.subtract(output_df).count()``` which is also giving same result as diff_df. Am i missing some thing silly here ?

Comment: @Vizag If you exclude the transformed columns from the compared data frames it should give you the correct result. With the above code, I can get the expected result. It's hard to debug this way, maybe you can add a reproducible example in your question.